# How to check attached property in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I need to know that how to check attached property (WPF) value in QuickWatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AttachedPropertyClassName.GetAttachedPropertyName(dependencyObject)
```

Concrete example:

```
Grid.GetRow(someGrid)
```